# SSIS packages fail with Pending Execution Status

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, sql-server-agent, ssis-2014

My packages have been running on our production environment for a couple of weeks until they started failing with very little information apart from packages having a pending execution status.

All packages fail regardless of the user executing them e.g. myself or the SQL Agent service account.

There is a cryptic error message in the windows log about activation permissions for the SQL Integration Services. Setting permissions for the accounts calling the package makes no difference,

I managed to get them working by repairing the SQL Server installation I couldn't see what repairs it had made.

Now following a reboot of the server all packages refuse to run. I have managed to get them to work by repairing the SQL Server installation again. This is obviously not a scalable solution.

I suspect that some group policy setting is overriding a local security setting and this is why it happens after some time or after a reboot.

Has anybody come across this issue before or have any ideas where to look.

Comment: have you checked the 'All Executions' report against the catalogue in Integration Services Catalogs? This may provide you with more specific information on what is causing problems.

Comment: @DimUser Yes I have checked the all executions report and it shows no messages, the report is blank

Comment: then potentially that suggests that the packages aren't even getting to execution stage. Does the account for SSIS service have the appropriate permissions, or is this still a local service account? Have you tried running a package in debug mode and checking the executions logs?

Comment: @DimUser as I said in my question they run then after some days they stop working and the only way i have managed to fix them is by running a repair. They run under NT Service\SQLAgent$InstanceName

Comment: If the packages are running as part of a SQLAgent job, have you tried recreating the catalog and the job.

Answer (score 1):

If the packages are running as part of a SQLAgent job, check the job for what user it's running as.  Check those permissions, and that could be your problem.  I just had to repair a situation like that.  Permissions got yanked from the wrong users, and it broke everything...

Comment: The job is running as the NT Service\SQLAgent$InstanceName account. The package needs no access to other servers. Repairing the SQL Server installation fixes the issue for a while. The Agent account is specified as SSIS user